# Android - AsyncTask class and Execute method

Tags: android

I have code using the AsyncTask class for populating a listView with several contacts from a database.

```
@Override
   protected void onResume() 
   {
      super.onResume();

       new MyTask().execute((Object[]) null);
    } // end method onResume
```

1.- Why do I pass this: `(Object[]) null)` as an argument?

See the AsyncTask code:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      //used for database conection purpose 
      ConectToDatabase databaseConnector = 
         new ConectToDatabase(ThisClass.this);


      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
      {
         databaseConnector.open();

         return databaseConnector.getMyContacts(); 
      } 

      // use the Cursor returned from the doInBackground method
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         //My cursorAdadper defined in early code
         contactAdapter.changeCursor(result);
         databaseConnector.close();
      } 
   }
```

Another AsyncTask issue:

```
delete.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
```

2.- Why do I pass this: `(new Long[] { rowID })` as an argument and not a simple (rowId)?

rowID is a a long type which contains the id of the contact selected in my previous class. That was extendend in a ListActivity. This previous class was populated by all my contacts obtained in my database. When I'm sent data in this class(by an intent) I want to recover the data of the single contact selected in my previous class, but in this case the code appears in this way: `new LoadMyContact().execute(rowID);` located in onResume method.

3.- Why do I pass only: `(rowID)` as an argument ?

`delete.execute(new Long[] { rowID });` is inside a menu, when the user confirm delete the contact we execute that sentence the code will be this for the delete(we are inside on a click button):

```
@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final ConectToDataBase databaseConnector = 
                  new ConectToDataBase(MySecondClass.this);


               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        databaseConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                        delete.execute(new Long[] { rowID });              
                      }
                  }; // end new AsyncTask
               delete.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            } /
```

Help with this three question and thanks.

Comment: In Java, `Long != long`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has the form `AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Return>` with `execute` using the `Param` type.

#1

It is possible to write `execute(null)`. Doing so results in the `Confusing 'null' argument to var-arg method` warning in IntelliJ IDEA. This warning notes that it is not wrapped as a single-element array. Therefore, as `Param` is `Object` in this case, `execute((Object[])null)` is used to supress the warning.

Since variable argument parameters don't have to have a value passed to them, you can use `execute()` instead.

#2 & #3

In this case, `Param` is `Long`, so the execute method has the form `execute(Long...)`. Without the variable argument syntactic sugar, this is the same as `execute(Long[])`. Therefore, the `new Long[]{ rowId }` is explicitly creating the `Long` array with a single element (`rowId`). As `rowId` is a `long`, the Java compiler automatically 'boxes' (wraps) that integer into a `Long` object -- the equivalent of writing `new Long(rowId)`.

As the `execute` method uses variable arguments, you don't need to allocate the `Long` array directly -- the Java compiler will do this for you -- so you can just write `execute(rowId)` instead. That is, the Java compiler is expanding `execute(rowId)` into `execute(new Long[]{ new Long(rowId) })`.

Therefore, #2 and #3 are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all your questions is an `AsyncTask` logic:

While defining `AsyncTask`, we need to declare 3 parameters:

`private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor>`

Like in your case above, you have given Object, Object, Cursor.

Now, 1st parameter is set during the "execute" call and is used by `doInBackGround()` function. This has been designed to be an array of defined type so that we can send multiple data. For example, we can do:

`myTask.execute(url1, url2, url3)` for my `AsysncTask` whose 1st parameter is URL. In `doInBackGround()` function, we can assess the as url[0], url[1], url[2]

2nd Parameter in `AsyncTask` is used by `onProgressUpdate()` function and it also expects to receive array of defined type.

3rd Parameter in `AsyncTask` is used by `onPostExecute()` function and is the value rerturned by `doInBackGround()` function. In need not be an array of defined type.

Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask { ... }

The below link details about `AsyncTask` which will answer all 3 question of yours:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @NightSky.. I hope it looks normal now. Thanks for pointing it out. Still learning to format things :)